Why can't I connect to the default port on localhost when using Milvus?
I'm just starting to use Milvus, but cannot connect to the port given in the example. I am running directly on my machine (i.e. not a Docker image), but cannot get initial exampe to work:
$ python
Python 3.10.14 (main, May  6 2024, 19:42:50) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymilvus
>>> pymilvus.__version__
'2.4.4'
>>> host="localhost"
>>> port = 19530
>>> from pymilvus import connections
>>> connections.connect("default",host=host,port=port)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/ShopTalk/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 147, in _wait_for_channel_ready
    grpc.channel_ready_future(self._channel).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/ShopTalk/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_utilities.py", line 162, in result
    self._block(timeout)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/ShopTalk/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_utilities.py", line 106, in _block
    raise grpc.FutureTimeoutError()
grpc.FutureTimeoutError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/ShopTalk/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/connections.py", line 447, in connect
    connect_milvus(**kwargs, user=user, password=password, token=token, db_name=db_name)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/ShopTalk/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/connections.py", line 398, in connect_milvus
    gh._wait_for_channel_ready(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/ShopTalk/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 150, in _wait_for_channel_ready
    raise MilvusException(
pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=2, message=Fail connecting to server on localhost:19530, illegal connection params or server unavailable)>
>>> 

I've tried to guarantee that 19530 is listening:
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
19530/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
19530/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)   

But this doesn't seem to make a difference. I suppose there's something `networky' that I'm missing here, but I have no idea what it is. The only installation instructions I saw were 'pip install -U milvus', which I did. What am I not doing here?

Which example are you referring to? The ones in the docs are using Docker or Kubernetes, and don't show how to start the server outside of that. Pip installs a Python client, not the server

@OneCricketeer - That was the issue
